# @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) generates org.springframework.validation.BindException

Tags: kotlin, datetime-format

I have an endpoint

```
@GetMapping
fun search(
    filter: GuaranteeApplicationFilter,
    @SortDefaults(
        SortDefault(sort = ["docNumber"], direction = Sort.Direction.DESC),
        SortDefault(sort = ["createTime"], direction = Sort.Direction.DESC),
        SortDefault(sort = ["id"], direction = Sort.Direction.DESC)
    ) page: PaginationParametersDto,
    @ApiParam(hidden = true) @AuthenticationPrincipal userId: String
): JsonItem<SliceDto<GuaranteeApplicationSearchDto>>
```

and a class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class GuaranteeApplicationFilter(
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    var docDateFrom: LocalDate?,
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    var docDateTo: LocalDate?,
    var docNumber: String?,
    var inn: String?,
    var shortName: String?,
    var amountFrom: BigDecimal?,
    var amountTo: BigDecimal?,
    var currency: String?,
    var type: String?,
    var status: String?,
    var liability: String?
) : DocumentFilter()
```

so when I pass a date string like `2022-08-02` I get **"Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate'"** error.

In debug mode conversion is successful
[[https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSSDJ.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu6Bf.png)
but then I get exception.

If I use `spring.mvc.format.date=yyyy-MM-dd` without `@DateTimeFormat` all works fine.

Comment: What? DATE The most common ISO Date Format yyyy-MM-dd — for example, "2000-10-31". And what's the difference between 2000-10-31 and 2022-08-02?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found the answer. It was quite easy. Just need to change:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
```

to

```
@field:DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
```